# NPM: Is it OK for a NPM executable to have an extension?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I've made a npm library and now I need to place executable to its `./bin` folder. Every other library on github has files in `./bin` with no extensions. However, my executable `./bin/foo.js` works fine. Is it OK to leave the extension?

I want to leave the extension because I am writing source file for the executable in Typescript, which by default compiles files with `.js` extension.